# RhinoMocks and Abstract Base Classes

Tags: c#, rhino-mocks

I'm trying to mock using System.Security.Cryptography.RandomNumberGenerator, which unfortunately is an abstract base class, not an interface.

When I try to set up an expectation in Rhino.Mocks:

```
int iterations = 10 ;
byte[] fakeHash = {0, 1, 3, 6};
mocks.Get<HashAlgorithm>().Expect(x => x.ComputeHash(Arg<byte[]>.Is.NotNull))
    .Return(fakeHash).Repeat.Times(iterations);
```

I get an exception thrown from the ABC:

> Test method
>   Tests.Utils.FooTest.BarTest
>   threw exception:  System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: buffer at
>   System.Security.Cryptography.HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash(Byte[] buffer)

The ABC is enforcing the invariant that passed argument is not null, but Rhino is passing a null. Note that this happens as part of the **setup** of the expectation/stub, *not* when it's called as part of the test.

How can I work around this, but still get both the Expectation that the method will be called, and the fake result I want? I could just make my own mock class, of course, but I'd prefer to find a way to do this that doesn't require that.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Exception is thrown because `ComputeHash` is not a virtual member. You can set expectations only on virtual or interface methods.
If you need to mock this class you need to create a wrapper with virtual members and mock it instead of real class.

Note that if you have a resharper -- that is trivial, just create a class, put HashAlgorithm as a field and select Generate / Delegating Methods. Then choose methods you need to mock and make them virtual :)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the `HashAlgorithm.ComputeHash` methods are not virtual and cannot be mocked by RhinoMocks.

```
public byte[] ComputeHash(Stream inputStream) { ... }
public byte[] ComputeHash(byte[] buffer) { ... }
public byte[] ComputeHash(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
```